# Call dropdown Click event on- button Click/jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown. I have a button too.
I have special requirement.

When a user click on the button, the dropdown should be expanded.

Comment: what you mean by "expanded" ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: shyju onnun ariyillengil mindathiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't achieve exactly what you want, I came up with alternative way. When the button is clicked you can set the drop down `size` dynamically to the amount of items it got, causing it to "open" and show all the items.

Then, when selecting an item you can set the `size` back to 1. This effectively has the same look and feel like what you want.

Complete code for this would be:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oDDL = document.getElementById("myselect");
    oDDL.onchange = function() {
        //drop down item selected, reset size back to 1 to "close" the list:
        this.size = 1;
    };

    var oButton = document.getElementById("btnOpenDropDown");
    oButton.onclick = function() {
        //set size to number of items to "open" the list:
        oDDL.size = oDDL.options.length;
        oDDL.focus();
    }
};​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/N8UGD/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to build a custom dropdown menu that has some kind of expand() method that shows the options in the dropdown. The default dropdown menu does not have such a thing, so you're stuck there.